# Boostrap Menu Formating Problems Meteor Js

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello and good afternoon. I am currently building a social networking application with the Meteor Js Stack but I am having a few problems with my nav bar wrapping on mobile. I tried setting my drop down to pull-right and it does but it stills wraps when the drop down is clicked.

```css
 html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }

.navbar-nav {
 margin:0;
 float:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
 float:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.navbar-default{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    margin-bottom: 250px;
}

.row {
    margin-top:80px;
}

#submitPost {
    width: 500px;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .row {
        margin-top: 135px;
    }


    #submitPost {
        width: 300px;
    }

}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          {{#linkTo route='root'}}
        <span style="font-size:1.7em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          {{/linkTo}}
        </li>
        <li>
          {{#linkTo route='messages'}}
        <span style="font-size:1.7em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          {{/linkTo}}
        </li>
         <li>
          {{#linkTo route='profile'}}
        <span style="font-size:1.7em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          {{/linkTo}}
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a style="font-size:1.7em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin"></a>
              <div id="submitPost" class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:17px;">

              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <ul style="font-size:1.7em" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       {{> loginButtons}}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        {{> yield}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot_1]

Additional Screenshots

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2yh3X9W-N9LWEM5VF9FYU9mMlE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This example may help or give you some ideas. You can make your main links/icons visible across all viewports and use the built in toggle for your form and lower navigation.

```css
.navbar-default.custom-navbar {
  background: #38A6EB;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
}
.custom-navbar ul.navbar-nav li.active > a {
  background: #007CC9;
  color: #fff;
}
.custom-navbar ul.navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.custom-navbar ul.navbar-nav li.active > a:focus {
  background: #fff;
  color: #007CC9;
}
.custom-navbar ul.navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.custom-navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle span.glyphicon,
.custom-navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover,
.custom-navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: none;
}
.custom-navbar .nav-icons {
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.custom-navbar .nav-icons span.glyphicon {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 20px
}
.custom-navbar .nav-icons a {
  color: #fff;
}
.custom-navbar #navbar-blog .control-label {
  color: #fff;
}
.btn.btn-blue {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #007CC9;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.nav-lower {
  height: 20px;
  background: #38A6EB;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar.nav-lower .navbar-toggle,
.navbar.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:hover {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
.navbar.nav-lower > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: left;
}
.navbar.nav-lower .navbar-brand {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 2500px) {
  .custom-navbar .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-left,
  .custom-navbar .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-toggle,
  .custom-navbar .navbar-toggle:hover,
  .custom-navbar .navbar-toggle:focus {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    background: none;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .custom-navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-nav {
    float: none !important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .custom-navbar .collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar.nav-lower .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: left;
    background: #38A6EB;
  }
}
.bg-primary {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default custom-navbar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>

      </button>
      <div class="nav-icons">
        <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></a><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-navbar">
      <!-- Non-collapsing right-side icons -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Profile</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Account</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <form id="navbar-blog" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="body">Body</label>
          <textarea name="body" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default nav-lower">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-lower-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand@website.com</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-lower-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-primary">Boostrap Mobile</div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```